# How to properly render JSX.Element or React.ReactNode type while mapping over array of objects in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have this sidebar data

```
export const adminSidebarData: SidebarProps["sidebarData"] = [
  {
    title: "Dashboard",
    link: "/admin/dashboard",
    IconComponent: <IconDashboard className="icon" />,
  },
  {
    title: "Users",
    link: "/admin/dashboard/users",
    IconComponent: <IconDashboard />,
  }
];
```

My typescript type for `sidebarData` is

```
sidebarData: {
    title: string;
    link: string;
    IconComponent: JSX.Element;
  }[];
```

And I am rendering the data in UI like:

```
{sidebarData.map((data) => {
          return (
            <Link href={data.link} className="w-full" key={data.link}>
              <div
                key={data.link}
                className="mx-2 flex w-full bg-white px-2 py-2"
              >
                {data.IconComponent}
                <p className="">{data.title}</p>
              </div>
            </Link>
          );
        })}
```

As you can see, I am rendering the icon like `{data.IconComponent}` I cannot pass dynamic props to component this way

But I wanted to render the component as `<data.IconComponent/>` or `<IconComponent/>` so that I will be able to pass props dynamically. Maybe changing the color based on the current route.
What change should I make to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it this way

```
type SidebarItem = {
  title: string;
  link: string;
  IconComponent: React.ComponentType<{ className?: string }>;
};
type SidebarProps = {
  sidebarData: SidebarItem[];
};
```

Comment: Much welcome @Bikrant